# Determine whether one value is divisible by another

Tags: numerics, numerical-value

How do I determine whether one number is evenly divisible by another in the case of large numbers, for example: `52^52 / 52!`

Comment: One (pedestrian) way is to divide and see if you get an integer. `In[2]:= IntegerQ[52^52/52!]

Out[2]= False`

Comment: `Divisible[52^52, 52!]` would be the obvious way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using

```
Mod[numerator,denominator]
```

If the return value is 0 it is evenly divisible, else it is not divisible.